# How to Calculate the Volume and Area Surface From the 3D Plot Using Matplotlib and Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hi all I want to know how to calculate the volume and the surface area of this 3D plot?

I am using the right size for the width and length and height.

this is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# vertices of a prism
v = np.array([[-2, -2, -2.5], [2, -2, -2.5], [2, 2, -2.5],  [-2, 2, -2.5], [2,0,2.5], 
        [-2,0,2.5]])
ax.scatter3D(v[:, 0], v[:, 1], v[:, 2])

# generate list of sides' polygons of our prism
verts = [ [v[0],v[1],v[4],v[5]], [v[0],v[3],v[5]],
 [v[2],v[1],v[4]], [v[2],v[3],v[5],v[4]], [v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3]]]

# plot sides
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts, 
 facecolors='cyan', linewidths=1, edgecolors='r', alpha=.25))

plt.show()
```

[image: 1]

Comment: There are math formulas for that should you dare searching for them. [ask]

Comment: And you don't compute that from the plot but the underlying data...

Comment: My question is to ask whether there is a way, this is good to upgrade numpy matplotlib and computer graphics in the future. I know there is prism formula out there. It would be great if Python can do such thing, decode volume and surface area out of a plot.

Comment: No python nor anything can't do that from the plot itself, at the very least because a "3d" plot is a projection in 2d and looses depth information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I wanted and the code works thanks to @Ali Redha

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# vertices of a prism
v = np.array([[-5, -2, -2.5], [5, -2, -2.5], [5, 2, -2.5],  [-5, 2, -2.5], [5,0,2.5], 
        [-5,0,2.5]])
ax.scatter3D(v[:, 0], v[:, 1], v[:, 2])

# generate list of sides' polygons of our prism
verts = [ [v[0],v[1],v[4],v[5]], [v[0],v[3],v[5]],
 [v[2],v[1],v[4]], [v[2],v[3],v[5],v[4]], [v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3]]]

# plot sides
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts, 
 facecolors='cyan', linewidths=1, edgecolors='r', alpha=.25))

# Calculate Volume and Surface Area
a=v[1]-v[0]
b=v[3]-v[0]
c=v[4]-v[1]

volume=np.dot(a,np.cross(b,c))

surface_area=2* (abs(a[0]*b[1]*c[2]) + abs(a[1]*b[2]*c[0]) + abs(a[2]*b[0]*c[1]))

# Annotation
ax.set_title("Prism")
ax.text(2,0,6.6,"Volume= {}".format(volume), size=10,
                           verticalalignment='center', rotation=270)
ax.text(2,0,7.2,"Surface Area = {}".format(surface_area), size=10,
                           verticalalignment='center', rotation=270)
plt.show()
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your code

```
a=v[1]-v[0]
b=v[3]-v[0]
c=v[4]-v[1]

Volume=np.dot(a,np.cross(b,c))

surface_area=2* (abs(a[0]*b[1]*c[2]) + abs(a[1]*b[2]*c[0]) + abs(a[2]*b[0]*c[1]))


print(volume)
print(Surface_area)
```